# Getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in <unknown file>:1' when using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I'm setting a variable to be equal to JSON text like so:

```
var httpResponseBackup = {"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"searchResult":["nada"]}]}
```

However, when I run my cloud code, it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in <unknown file>:1
```

Based on what I've found by googling this error, it has to do with the following line of code:

```
var ebayResponse = JSON.parse(httpResponseBackup);
```

Am I formatting the JSON text in `httpResponseBackup` incorrectly?

Comment: i tried the same thing and i also had the same exception which you mentioned above. Only workaround i had was to look out at the json and rather than parsing the json, i have to access it using data.object.properpty or data.objArr[0].property. May be somebody can help us with using the json.parse.

Comment: Transcendence is correct.  Just add single quotes around your json like: var httpResponseBackup = '{"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"searchResult":["nada"]}]}';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSON.parse` expects a string, stringified JSON. You are passing in something that's already a JSON object. Therefore you can set your response to the object:

```
var ebayResponse = httpResponseBackup;
```

Alternatively you could set your httpReponseBackup to the string value:

```
var httpResponseBackup = '{"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"searchResult":["nada"]}]}'
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

```
var httpResponseBackup = {"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"searchResult":["nada"]}]};

var httpResponseBackupString = '{"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"searchResult":["nada"]}]}';
```

**Then:**

```
JSON.stringify(httpResponseBackup) == httpResponseBackupString
```

**And:**

`JSON.parse(httpResponseBackupString)` will return a new object with the same structure as `httpResponseBackup`.